# script output in 2 columns instead of 1

Tags: php, html, mysql

This scripts below outputs all specifications of a product on different lines (who switch between white and grey color).

I want the script to output the specifications 2 by 2.

So instead of:

```
label - value 
label - value 
label - value
```

I would like:

```
label - value    label - value 
label - value    label - value 
label - value    label - value
```

Does anyone know on how I should achieve this?

The current code is:

```
<?php
$color='grey';
$attributes = $_product->getAttributes();
foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
    if ($attribute->getIsVisibleOnFront() and $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product)) 
    {
    ?>
        <div class="row-<?php $color=($color=='grey')? 'white' : 'grey'; echo $color; ?>">
            <div class="name-detail">
                <?php echo $attribute->getFrontend()->getLabel($_product); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="description">
                <?php echo $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Use a `for` loop instead.  You can then configure the number of columns based on the `$i` being a multiple of `2`.

Answer (score 0):

Just have a counter tell you if you're on `%2` or not.

This should work (not tested, but enough to get the point here):

```
<?php
$color='grey';
$i = 0;
$attributes = $_product->getAttributes();
foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
    if ($attribute->getIsVisibleOnFront() and $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product)) 
    {
        if ($i % 2)
        {
?>
        <div class="row-<?php $color=($color=='grey')? 'white' : 'grey'; echo $color; ?>">
<?php
        }
?> 
            <div class="name-detail">
                <?php echo $attribute->getFrontend()->getLabel($_product); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="description">
                <?php echo $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); ?>
            </div>
<?php
        if (($i + 1) % 2)
        {
?>
        </div>
<?php
        }
        $i++;
    }
}
if (($i + 1) % 2)
{
?>
    </div>
<?php
}
?>
```

I tried to stick to your coding style here.

Just so you know, you can use `echo` to output html, which would have given something this way:

```
<?php
  $color='grey';
  $i = 0;
  $attributes = $_product->getAttributes();
  foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
    if ($attribute->getIsVisibleOnFront() && $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product)) {
      if ($i % 2)
        echo '<div class="row-' . (($color == 'grey') ? 'grey' : 'white') . '">';
      echo '<div class="name-detail">' . $attribute->getFrontend()->getLabel($_product) . '</div>';
      echo '<div class="description">' . $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) . '</div>';
      if (($i + 1) % 2)
        echo '</div>';
      $i++;
    }
  }
  if (($i + 1) % 2)
    echo '</div>';
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick help. 

With your solution the first variable is outputted and styled and the other values are outputted without style. 

So it look like:

label - value (styled)

label
value
label
value
...etc

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I've edited the fail here I think, which was of the last if not placed correctly.

Comment: Hello. 

It fails at the "$i++" line with the error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting ',' or ';' in %path%

Sorrie! Hope you have another good idea!

Comment: Seriously ? Couldn't you debug the missing semicolon ?

Comment: I feel myself very stupid ;-) But what is the missing semicolon? Where should it be?

Comment: Your debugger just told you. If it fails at `$i++`, it means the error is just before. And as you could see before I edited, there was a missing semicolon after `echo </div>` on the line before.